# Finding the best mapping from one 3D space to another 4D space from data

Tags: optimization, gradient-descent

A buddy of mine is doing materials testing to find the right combination of ingredients to get a certain combination of features (think viscosity, strength, etc) he has 3 inputs and it’s success is measured by 4 outputs.
How do I find the approximate optimal mapping from one space to another from his testing data?

I feel like it’s a gradient decent problem? or maybe a statistical modeling problem? but I’m not sure how to format it or what to google so I can find the right Python package to use!

Anyone know the kind of problem this is called?

I’m betting it’s something like

```
Min(F(x, y, z)-(a, b, c, d))
```

Over all k from 0 to n, where n is his max number of tests, but how to I find F for that?

Comment: You first need to define the model $F(x,y,z)$ and then optimize perhaps its parameters. For instance $F(x,y,z)= Av$, where $v=[x \;y \; z]^\top$ and $A$ is a $4 \times 3$ matrix which you wish to learn, so the parameter of your function

Comment: That makes sense! And then I imagine I just use GD to converge to the right weights for that matrix?

Comment: Yes, for instance, as long as your optimization problem is convex